# Revolut visa Debit card not detected by libnfc6

Tags: c, linux, nfc, lib-nfc

Trying to read various payment cards using PN532 NFC RFID Module.
libnfc6 sucessfully polls most of the nfc cards and even [mobile payment method](https://github.com/jesparza/nfc_creditcard_reader/blob/master/nfc_creditcard_reader.c) is detected, but none of my Revolut cards are detected by [nfc-poll](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/libnfc-1.8.0/examples/nfc-poll.c) app.

libnfc was compiled locally from [libnfc-1.8.0 git tag](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/tree/libnfc-1.8.0).

My current polling setup:

```
  const uint8_t uiPollNr = 20;
  const uint8_t uiPeriod = 2;
  const nfc_modulation nmModulations[] = {
    { .nmt = NMT_ISO14443A, .nbr = NBR_106 },
    { .nmt = NMT_ISO14443A, .nbr = NBR_212 },
    { .nmt = NMT_ISO14443A, .nbr = NBR_424 },
    { .nmt = NMT_ISO14443B, .nbr = NBR_106 },
    { .nmt = NMT_FELICA, .nbr = NBR_212 },
    { .nmt = NMT_FELICA, .nbr = NBR_424 },
    { .nmt = NMT_JEWEL, .nbr = NBR_106 },
    { .nmt = NMT_ISO14443BICLASS, .nbr = NBR_106 },
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Nice picture. Probably update the library to latest version if it is maintained.

Comment: Compiled from libnfc-1.8.0 git tag which is also the [last released](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/releases/tag/libnfc-1.8.0)

Comment: Not an answer yet, but buying new PN532 NFC RFID Module helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buying new PN532 NFC RFID Module solved the issue.